# distance calculation between camera and depth pixel?

Tags: python, opencv, object, depth

I need to calculate distance from camera to depth image pixel. I searched through internet but I found stereo image related info and code example where I need info for depth image.

Here, I defined depth image in gray scale(0-255) and I defined a particular value( let range defined 0 pixel value is equal to 5m and 255 pixel value is equal to 500m in gray scale). 
camera's intrinsic (focal length, image sensor format) and extrinsic (rotation and transition matrix) is given. I need to calculate distance from different camera orientation and rotation.

I want to do it using opencv python. Is there any specific documentation and code example regarding this?

Or any further info is necessary to find this.

Comment: Can you provide some more details? How is your data formatted?  What do you mean by "and I defined a particular value...."  It's not very clear what you're asking.

Comment: I explained more details. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

The content of my research is the same as yours, but I have a problem now. I use `stereocalibrate()` to calibrate the binocular camera, and found that the obtained translation matrix is very different from the actual baseline distance. In addition, the parameters used in `stereocalibrate()` are obtained by calibrating the two cameras with `calibrate()`.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask.
You can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question once you have enough reputation: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties